# Direct URL to a "Full page" runnable snippet from a specific answer

Tags: feature-request

Is there an URL that directly goes to the "Full page" view of a given snippet, in a given question or answer?

Example: in the answer [Zoom on a Plotly heatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75792497/zoom-on-a-plotly-heatmap/76142244#76142244), is there an URL that directly displays the runnable snippet in a full page?

Comment: Does that snippet actual run as expected? Perhaps choose an example that isn't blocked by default by [NoScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoScript) or [uBlock Origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UBlock_Origin)? *"`22:04:30.590 Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.22.0.min.js (“script-src-elem”).`"*